# Can I response.end() inside request.on(end)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm learning node.js. I have a client form, from which I send to my server some data and refactor it somehow in a module *makeRequest*. The module returns a promise, which I want to resolve with response to the client.
So I might think that I could do something like this:

```
let post = '';

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const readHtml = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/view/form.html', 'utf8');
    readHtml.pipe(res);
});

server.on('request', processPost);

function processPost(request, response) {
    let body = '';

    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

            if (body.length > 1e6) {
                request.connection.destroy();
            }
        });

        request.on('end', function () {
            post = JSON.parse(body);

            makeRequest(post.text)
                .then(data => {
                    response.end(data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });
    }
}

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

This for me means that as soon as I retreive the refactored data I immediately send it back to client with response.end(data).
But suddenly the data does not return to the client if I do like this. It does, if I write response.end(data) after request.on('end'). But this is synchronous way and therefore when I run such code, there will be no data anyhow.

What can I do to make it work as I want to?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but look at your `http.createServer` call where you **unconditionally** pipe a static file to the client, regardless of the request type. Thus, even on a `POST` request, the client gets the contents of the file. What you have later doesn't change much, or rather - confuses the runtime - you not only pipe a static file but also try to return **another** respose. If, for example, you call `http.createServer` **without** any argument, your POST handling will work correctly. But, as I said, I'm not sure what you're up to, then.

Comment: readHtml.pipe(res) is made so when I open localhost:3000 the html form would be there. Maybe there are other ways to get that page?

Comment: Yes, have an `if` inside the function you attach as a request handler. I'll make an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as said in a discussion below the question, you just want a default page accessed in a browser, make it conditional

```
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if ( req.method == "GET" ) {
    const readHtml = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/view/form.html', 'utf8');
    readHtml.pipe(res);    
  }
});
```

This way both GETs and POSTs are handled correctly.

My advice would be to use a more organized approach using any framework, Express should do fine. This way you could be a more clean approach to define different routes and request types.

Comment: Glad to hear that, it would be nice to accept this as an answer then.